# È possibile usare la particella "ne" per fare riferimento a una frase che risponde alla domanda "che cosa?"?

Tags: grammar, particles

Ho imparato che si usa "ne" per fare riferimento a una frase che risponde alla domanda "di che cosa". 
Ad esempio:

> Hai paura dei ragni? – Sì, ne ho paura.

Tuttavia, ho trovato, per caso, il seguente proverbio:

> Morto un papa, se ne fa un altro.

Questa frase, l'ho cambiata in

> Morto un papa, si fa un altro dei papi.

Ma un italiano mi ha detto che era  sbalgliata ma non ha potuto darmi delle delucidazioni.
La sua frase era:

> Morto un papa, si fa un altro papa.

Perché "ne" è usata qui per fare riferimento a una frase che risponde alla domanda "che cosa"?

Comment: Si tratta di un [complemento partitivo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/complemento-partitivo_(La-grammatica-italiana)/), simile all'esempio "alcune **delle camicie**": un altro **dei papi**. Una delle funzioni della particella "ne" è quella di sostituire un complemento partitivo.

Comment: @Charo direi proprio di no; vedi http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ne1/

Comment: In che senso no, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica? Proprio la voce che citi dice testualmente “assai frequente in luogo di un genitivo partitivo”.

Comment: OP, attenzione, [questo “se” è una forma debole del pronome “si”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/se3/) che viene usata solo prima di certi altri pronomi (lo, la, le, li, ne). Quindi, indipendentemente dal resto, la forma corretta è “si fa un altro”.

Comment: @Charo l'accezione 1b, "Con valore più chiaramente pronominale"; "assai frequente" (partitivo) non significa *sempre*. Nella frase "ne parlerò ai nostri soci" non c'è alcun partitivo.

Comment: @linuxfan, ma la frase "ne parlerò", si può cambiare in "parlerò DI qualcosa". Dunque, si risponde sempre alla domanada "Di/Da che cosa?" e no "che cosa?".

Comment: @Charo dunque, la frase "fare un altro papa" non è la frase corretta che esprime la stessa idea di ciò nel proverbio, ma  invece " fare un altro dei papi".

Comment: @DaG, capisco! L'ho corretta grazie.

Comment: @user1173ecc non capisco il tuo commento, e trovo un po' d'incongruenza fra il titolo e il contenuto della domanda. Comunque, la risposta al titolo della tua domanda è senz'altro sì.

Comment: OP: "Fare un altro papa" è perfettamente corretto. L'idea del modo di dire è quella che ha spiegato @egreg nella sua risposta. Sarebbe un po' come dire "ce ne sono tanti, di possibili papi" (qui ho adoperato una dislocazione a destra), "ne possiamo prendere uno qualsiasi", come nell'esempio dei mattoni che ha fatto egreg. Tutti questi "ne" hanno funzione di complemento partitivo.

Comment: Sì, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: la particella "ne" ha altre funzioni, ma non credo che questo sia l'oggetto della domanda. Nel mio primo commento ho scritto "una delle funzioni".

Comment: @Linuxfan, sorry my Italian is not that good I might have failed to said what I wanted. Anyway, what I wanted to say  is that in the phrase "ne parlerò", ne refers to another phrase that could be made into " di + qualcosa" so whenever ne is used there it replaces some phrase of the form "di (or da) + qualcosa".

Comment: @linuxfan, please if you think you can made the title or the body clearer, feel free to modify it.

Comment: @Charo, I wanted to say that even though "fare un altro papa" is perfectly correct it  is not equivalent to "ne fare un altro papa" but rather to "ne fare un altro dei papi". Even altro is used as a noun in "fare un altro dei papi" and an adj in "fare un altro papa".  Am I  correct?

Comment: @OP: I don't have the time now, perhaps later and perhaps it is not necessary. Maybe I will post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modi di dire, le battute di spirito, le frasi idiomatiche e altri simili oggetti linguistici spesso sfuggono alle rigide classificazioni grammaticali. Qui c'è un piccolo paradosso nel considerare l'elezione del Papa come una faccenda del tutto normale:

> rotto un vaso, se ne fa un altro

potrebbe dire un vasaio. È un partitivo, ma non può veramente essere esplicitato in

> se si rompe un vaso, si fa un altro dei vasi

che non è idiomatico. Una versione con il partitivo esplicito sarebbe *si fa un'altra di quelle cose che si chiamano vasi*. Ma *una di quelle cose che si chiamano vasi* è precisamente *un vaso*.

Dunque il problema è nel verbo *fare* più che nella struttura grammaticale.

La struttura è la stessa di *rotto un mattone, se ne prende un altro*, che può essere adoperata in campo edilizio. Meglio ancora: *se si rompe un mattone, se ne prende un altro*.

Togliendo il pronome la frase sui mattoni diventerebbe *se si rompe un mattone, si prende un altro dei mattoni* (con il partitivo esplicito), ma sarebbe più scorrevole con *si prende un altro mattone*.

Comment: Grazie per la tua spiegazione.

Comment: Mi sembra una buona risposta. Tuttavia, non mi è del tutto chiaro che questo uso della particella *ne* sia qualcosa di specifico di modi di dire,  battute di spirito, frasi idiomatiche, ecc. Potrei dire, per esempio, "l'insegnante di matematica è assente per malattia, ma adesso ne abbiamo un'altra".

Comment: @Charo Il problema qui è che non si tratta di insegnanti di matematica, dei quali ce n'è molti (con il *ne* pleonastico). È l'uso specifico di *papa* che ne fa una frase particolare.

Comment: ...a parte il fatto che in questo momento di papi ce ne sono due, anche se uno è emerito. :) Più seriamente, se anche in ogni momento ci fosse un papa solo, l'insieme degli uomini che sono, sono stati e possono diventare papi ha centinaia di elementi. Tutto sommato non è diverso dall'esempio dell'insegnante di matematica: in ogni momento l'insegnante di matematica della 3ª L della tal scuola è uno solo, ma in una frase come quella il “ne” fa riferimento a un possibile insegnante, e quindi a un insieme con molti elementi.

Comment: @DaG Discordo. Il paradosso qui è considerare la creazione di un nuovo papa come una faccenda del tutto normale.

Comment: @egreg: Non mi è chiaro da cosa discordi. Sia di “insegnanti di matematica della 3ª L” sia di “papi” in ogni momento ce n'è, o ce ne dovrebbe essere uno; quando per qualche motivo smette di esserci se ne nomina al più presto un altro e così via. Le differenze sono solo nelle scale temporali, nell'importanza dell'incarico etc., ma non mutano la sintassi della frase in cui compaiono.

Comment: Va bene, @egreg: "Il dirigente della scuola andrà presto in pensione: il prossimo anno scolastico ce ne sarà un altro".

Comment: @DaG Ho modificato la struttura

Answer (score 3):

Per completare la risposta di @egreg, vorrei aggiungere che, in questo caso, la particella *ne* sostituisce un *complemento partitivo*.

Come spiega questo [articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/complemento-partitivo_(La-grammatica-italiana)/),

> il *complemento partitivo* è un complemento indiretto che indica l’insieme all’interno del quale si trova l’elemento di cui si parla.

Ecco alcuni esempi tratti dallo stesso articolo (il complemento partitivo appare in grassetto):

> - Un etto **di prosciutto**
> - Se solo potessi avere un po’ **dei tuoi soldi**!
> - Quale **tra quelle** è la tua automobile?
> - Ho appena finito di stirare alcune **delle camicie** di tuo padre
> - Ventotto **dei pazienti ricoverati**
> - Nicola è il meno simpatico **della sua compagnia** di amici.

Quello che appare in modo implicito nella frase della domanda è "un altro **di tutti i possibili papi**", simile all'esempio "alcune **delle camicie**" di sopra: l'idea sarebbe che si sta indicando un elemento dalla "totalità dei possibili papi".

Il libro [*Punti difficili della grammatica italiana*](https://books.google.es/books?id=N_SSAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=particella+ne+%22complemento+partitivo%22&source=bl&ots=NuNllR5gSF&sig=ACfU3U0QYL9dqz2oQrJzQfLStUfKiNOuYw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlmbizvMTpAhXBzIUKHd4MD0M4ChDoATAFegQIAxAB#v=onepage&q=particella%20ne%20%22complemento%20partitivo%22&f=false), di Adriano Bernareggi, spiega che una delle funzioni della particella *ne* è quella di sostituire un complemento partitivo:

> *La particella partitiva*. 
>   Con *ne* si esprime anche il complemento partitivo, cioè quello che indica l'entità di cui si considera una parte (grande, piccola o nulla non importa): "ho tanta frutta, ne vuoi un po'?" – "grazie, non ne avevo più". Anche in questo caso l'entità può essere metaforica o morale, e allora il complemento si confonde con quello di specificazione o di argomento: "di questo non ne voglio parlare", "di questo ne sono convinto".

Nella frase della domanda, l'entità di cui si considera una parte ("un altro"), che è stata sostituita da *ne*, è "di tutti i possibili papi".

Comment: grazie per le delucidazioni.

Answer (score 0):

> Morto un papa, se ne fa un altro

che significa che ci sono poche cose irrimediabili, anche la perdita di ciò che sembra unico non è grave perché quella cosa non è unica. Per questo motivo la frase dice "un papa" e non "il Papa": per sottolineare che di papi ce ne sono stati diversi, uno via l'altro.

La trasformazione di frase che riporti:

> Morto un papa, si fa un altro dei papi

esprime un complemento partitivo, che stride per diversi motivi. Primo, il partitivo è espresso male perché manca un confronto tra due quantità, come si trova per esempio in questa frase:

> Devo studiare tre papi, ma per ora ne ho studiato solo uno. (ne => di quelli; il confronto o ripartizione è fra *tre* e *uno*)

Secondo, c'è una discordanza tra "un papa" (singolare) prima della virgola e "dei papi" (plurale) dopo la virgola, quindi non si può  abbinarli e la frase risulta slegata. Terzo, il partitivo deve citare un insieme/quantità esistente da ripartire, ma
nel momento in cui si crea una cosa nuova, questa cosa ancora non esiste e perciò non può appartenere
ad alcun insieme - almeno in questa frase sui papi.

Come riporta https://www.skuola.net/italiano-medie/grammatica-medie/complemento-partitivo.html, il complemento partitivo "è introdotto dalle preposizioni di, tra, fra", "risponde alle domande
 *tra chi?, tra che cosa?*", e "si trova in dipendenza di espressioni che indicano quantità".

C'è da notare che, nella grande quantità di complementi, alcuni esoterici come "di materia", "di origine", "di provenienza", "di allontanamento", ci possono essere ambiguità e sovrapposizioni,
e il partitivo a volte può essere sostituito da un altro complemento. Per esempio:

> Ecco tre carte: scegline due (ne => delle/fra le/dalle "[tre] carte")

esprime un partitivo, se s'interpreta "due delle tre", oppure un complemento di origine o provenienza, se s'interpreta "due dalle tre", cioé due da quel gruppo di tre carte.

Tornando alla domanda, la trasformazione:

> Morto un papa, se ne fa un altro  =>  Morto un papa, si fa un altro papa

è totalmente corretta, la particella *ne* sostituisce "papa" nel senso "di papa". La stessa frase, espressa con ridondanza, sarebbe:

> Morto un papa se ne fa un altro... di papa.

ed è un **complemento di specificazione**, perché indica "di che cosa" se ne fa un altro (di che cosa si fa una copia).

Alcuni esempi di questo complemento sono:

> Ho finito la riunione: ora te ne parlo. (di questa riunione)
>   Ti do questi soldi, e fanne buon uso. (di questi soldi)
>   E' questo il tuo disegno? Fanne un altro! (di tuo disegno)

Questo complemento può essere capito meglio con un esempio di dialogo al telefono, disturbato, cosicché parti di una frase non vengono comprese:

> Si è rotta la fgrzzzjh: me ne compri una?
>   Me ne compri una? Di cosa? (notare il *di*, suggerito dalla particella *ne*)
>   Di lampadina: me ne compri una, di lampadina?

oppure con frasi incomplete o sgrammaticate:

> Ecco il documento, fai una copia
>   Una copia di questo documento, giusto?
>   Sì, sì: ti do questo documento, fanne una copia (di questo documento)

o ancora:

> Ho fatto un salto, faccio un altro
>   Un altro cosa?
>   Un altro salto. Avrei dovuto dire "Ho fatto un salto, ne faccio un altro"

Negli esempi riportati, così come nella frase sui papi, il complemento di specificazione ha funzione esplicativa, non attributiva o possessiva (https://www.analisi-logica.it/grammatica/specificazione.html).

Si può pensare che a volte non si tratta di complemento di specificazione ma di un partitivo:

> Mi hai fatto un buon caffè: fammene un altro [di quei buoni caffè]

dove la parte sottintesa (quei buoni caffè) sarebbe "la quantità iniziale da ripartire". E' un'interpretazione forse accettabile, ma è una forzatura far combaciare "quei buoni caffè"
con "il buon caffè che mi hai fatto prima". Parimenti, la frase

> Questo mattone non va bene, dammene un altro

non è un partitivo, perché da nessuna parte cita "il mucchio di mattoni", "i dieci mattoni" o simili; dice invece "questo mattone" (ben preciso), e dice "un altro" che significa
"diverso da questo" (perché questo non va bene).

Un testo abbastanza approfondito sulla particella *ne* è il seguente: https://www.gicas.net/ne.html

Comment: Trovo questa risposta un po' confusa. Nell'esempio del riassunto, *ne* sostituisce a *del film* e, cioè, nei termini dell'OP, risponde alla domanda "di che cosa?" (come anche *dei ragni* nell'esempio dell'OP). Poi, tutto il resto della spiegazione è per dire che la funzione del *ne* nel proverbio della domanda è quella di un "complemento di specificazione" invece di un "complemento partitivo"?

Comment: In che senso “farne” nel primo esempio non è un esempio di specificazione/partitivo?

Comment: Questo tipo di risposte mi fa pensare al [_Codex Seraphinianus_](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Seraphinianus).

Comment: Secondo la mia opinione personale (che può essere non condivisa da altri), che un certo sintagma preposizionale si debba chiamare "complemento partitivo" oppure "complemento di specificazione" è qualcosa di irrilevante: non riuscirò a capire mai l'ossessione degli italiani per fare questo tipo di classificazioni dei complementi.

Comment: @egreg non capisco; non c'è scritto da nessuna parte che il primo esempio "non è ... specificazione/partitivo". Comunque la frase sul film è un complemento di specificazione (certamente non un partitivo).

Comment: @Charo: È vero, la bizantina tassonomia dei complementi nelle grammatiche scolastiche tende a essere eccessiva, anche se nelle scuole odierne lo è meno di un tempo. Il senso che potrebbe avere, e per cui probabilmente è stata introdotta, è quello propedeutico all'eventuale studio del latino e del greco, in cui costruzioni che in italiano sono simili richiedono casi o preposizioni diverse. Un esempio classico è quello della distinzione fra complemento d'agente (persona) e di causa efficiente (cosa), che in italiano non ha molta ragion d'essere, ma in latino corrisponde a costruzioni diverse.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Cito: *dove la particella ne risponde alla domanda "che cosa"*; a me pare risponda a *di che cosa*.

Comment: @egreg sono d'accordo, ma questo non c'entra con "non è un esempio di specificazione/partitivo". Continuo a non cogliere il senso. La differenza fra "che cosa" e "di che cosa" mi pare trascurabile in quel contesto.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica L'inizio è “Assolutamente sì” (cioè, è possibile che *ne* risponda a “che cosa”) e prosegue con un esempio nel quale *ne* dovrebbe fare questo, ma nella realtà risponde a *di che cosa*.

Comment: @egreg hai ragione, ho interpretato male la domanda, ingannato dall'Italiano incerto dell'utente. Ma rimango dell'opinione che non si tratti di partitivo, cosa che le altre due risposte sostengono, così ho voluto scrivere una risposta articolata con molti esempi per chiarire il concetto così diverso.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Nota anche che nel libro che ho citato nella mia risposta, in riferimento al "complemento partitivo", si afferma che "il complemento si confonde con quello di specificazione o di argomento". Diciamo che si tratta della particella *ne* con valore partitivo e non ha tanta importanza se il complemento che sostituisce si chiama "partitivo", "di specificazione" o "di argomento".

Comment: @charo c'è una differenza enorme invece, che ti costringe a inventare un implicito ma improbabile "tutti i papi possibili". La particella *ne* non ha *sempre* valore partitivo.